# ASP.Net Core : Cannot open localdb requested by the login

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, localdb

**Prompt：**
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SqlException: Cannot open database "MoviesContext-8287b737-12b5-4c1c-8bf5-6259ea1d208b" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'D-PC\D'.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, object providerInfo, bool redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, bool applyTransientFaultHandling)

I had run the following commands in the command prompt in my project's catalog before(already made my model and made a my own Dbcontext):

`dotnet restore
dotnet ef migrations add Initial
dotnet ef database update`

I have checked out every method on the Internet, but all of them didn't happened in the ASP.Net Core project(**Visual Studio 2017**). In those ways, I cannot find where to acess the SQL serve or the web.config file.

Comment: 2 Questions: 1. Are you hosting the application in IIS? - this scenario is unsupported with localdb  2. did you create the localdb with a different user (i.e. create with local user, but run as admin)?

Comment: 1.I am hosting the app in IIS Express, which is default. And I followed the official document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model). So how should I process with this problem?  2.only single user

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run the following command in the Package Manager Console to create the migration class that will prepare the database for its first use:

**Add-Migration Initial**

When this command has finished, you will see a Migrations folder in the Visual Studio
Solution Explorer window. This is where Entity Framework Core stores its migration classes.
Run the following command to create the database and run the migration commands:

**Update-Database**

It can take a moment for the database to be created, but once the command has
completed, you can see the effect of creating and using the database by starting.

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to check that the database is created and, if necessary, create
This is done by the **context.Database.EnsureCreated();**

For example:

```
    public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            ApplicationDЬContext context = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDЬContext>();
if (!context.Database.EnsureCreated())
                context.Database.Migrate();
            if (!context.Products.Any())
            {
                context.Products.AddRange(
                new Product
                {
                    Name = "Soccer Ball ",
                    Description = "FIFA-approved size and weig",
                    Category = "Soccer",
                    Price = 19.50m
                },
                new Product
                {
                    Name = "Stadium",
                    Description = " Flat - packed 35,000- seat stadium",
                    Category = "Soccer",
                    Price = 79500
                }                
                );
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Comment: `context.Database.Migrate()` is supposed to create the database if it does not already exist. Why is there a need for a call to `EnsureCreated()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the database does not exist when the program is running. Create it.
Create a static class called 'Seed' and add following code:

```
public static class Seed
{
    public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var provider = scope.ServiceProvider;
            var context = provider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
            var userManager = provider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
            var roleManager = provider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

            context.Database.Migrate();

            const string userName="rainytears@test.com";
            const string password="123Aa.";
            const string roleName="Admin";

             var roleExist = roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName).Result;

            if (!roleExist)
            roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            var hasUser = userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName).Result;

             if (hasUser == null)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    UserName = userName,
                    Email = userName
                };

                var createUser = userManager.CreateAsync(user, password).Result;

                if (createUser.Succeeded)
                {
                    var confirmationToken = userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user).Result;
                    var result = userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, confirmationToken).Result;
                    userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, roleName).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then open Startup.cs and add RoleManager to Configure, As follow:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
```

Finally, call the Initialize function as follow:

```
     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        Seed.Initialize(app.ApplicationServices);

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```